# How can i split an 1D array to 2D array with specific size of column?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a one dimensional array `arr1D[i]` and i want it to convert in two dimensional array `arr2D[i][j]`, where the size of column in 2D array should be 512 and row size can be any thing. For example, if i have 1D array with size `arr1D[1024]` then the corresponding 2D array should be `arr2D[2][512]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
int len=arr1D.length();
if(len%512 !=0))
len= len/512 +1;
else
len=len/512;

int arr2D= new int[len][512];
int k=0;
for(int i=0; i<len-1; i++)
{

 for(int j=0; j<512; j++)
 {
  arr2D[i][j]=arr1D[k];
  k++;
                if (k==arr1D.length())
                     break;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about two forloops to copy them:

```
2darray[][];
size1d = 1024;
num_colums = 512;
num_rows = size1d/num_colums;
for(i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
     for(j = 0; j < num_colums; j++){
          2darray[i][j] = 1darray[i*num_colums+j];
      }
 }
```

This is just pseudocode, but with a few tweeks it should work; hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can easily create it by doing

`yourtype arr2D[][] = new yourtype[arr1D.length/2][512]` `// yourtype :=[int,float,..]`

Now all depends on you, how you are going to copy those elements of `arr1d` in `arr2d`